# My JPA named Query is failing to compile when I upgrade to java 11

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql, apache-ranger

My same JPQL query was working on java 8, when I upgraded to java 11 it stopped working.
I am using eclipselink implementation.
query

```
<named-query name="XXDataHist.findLatestByObjectClassTypeAndObjectIdAndEventTime">

    <query>select obj from XXDataHist obj WHERE obj.objectId = :objectId AND
    obj.objectClassType = :classType AND
    obj.createTime &lt;= :createTime ORDER BY obj.id DESC</query>
</named-query>
```

and it fails with below error,

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException|
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [defaultPU] failed.
Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.|
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException|
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select obj from XXDataHist obj where 
obj.objectId = :objectId and |             obj.objectClassType = :classType and |  
obj.createTime <= :createTime ORDER BY obj.id DESC]. |[16, 26] 
The abstract schema type 'XXDataHist' is unknown.
|[37, 49] The state field path 'obj.objectId' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
|[66, 85] The state field path 'obj.objectClassType' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
|[103, 117] The state field path 'obj.createTime' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
|[142, 148] The state field path 'obj.id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Entity class :

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "x_data_hist")
public class XXDataHist implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "x_data_hist_SEQ", sequenceName = "x_data_hist_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "x_data_hist_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
    protected Date createTime = DateUtil.getUTCDate();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
    protected Date updateTime = DateUtil.getUTCDate();

    @Column(name = "version")
    protected Long version;

    @Column(name = "obj_guid")
    protected String objectGuid;

    @Column(name = "obj_class_type")
    protected Integer objectClassType;

    @Column(name = "obj_id")
    protected Long objectId;

    @Column(name = "obj_name")
    protected String objectName;

    
    @Column(name = "action")
    protected String action;

    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "from_time")
    protected Date fromTime;

    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "to_time")
    protected Date toTime;

    
    @Column(name = "content")
    protected String content;

//constructor equals toString , getters and setters 
}
```

I am just wondering why is it working properly with java 8 and fails with java 11, I need to fix this query If it has any issue which was allowed in java 8 but not in java 11.

Answer (score 0):

You need [EclipseLink version > 3](https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/releases/3.0.php) for JDK 11 support

Comment: but when I upgrade my eclipselink version,  I see other errors like class does not implement the requested interface.                                                                                   found.[ERROR ] [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:313): Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEntityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource

Comment: [/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Comment: Try using the latest 2.7.x releases then - they may work but are just not certified to. EclipseLink 3.0 supports Jakarta persistence libraries (JPA 3.0) which replace Java Persistence (JPA 2.2?) so will require some package renaming and supported containers (Spring?) - it isn't just a library switch.

Comment: Thanks so much @Chris , latest 2.7.6  EclipseLink jar did help with java 11.